# The best practice to backup a system

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, backup

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Virtual Machine[VirtualBox] and I want to do some modifications in it. But I can't predict how it can influence on my system. What it the best practice to backup it?

It's clear that I can just backup my Virtual Machine but I don't know if it's a good practice?

Comment: There's no problem in backing up your vm. You can also make snapshots

Comment: It's great. But it's a pity for me that you are posting an answer as a comment but not as a real answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice for this is usually using *snapshots*, a feature provided by many virtualization hypervisors, including VirtualBox. One can revert to earlier snapshot within seconds to get back to the point of taking it.

For a consistent and quick snapshot I recommend you shut down the VM before taking the snapshot.

Comment: It's great, I didn't know about such functionality. Thank you very much.